# Сопоставить и пересчитать значения массивов PHP

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Доброго времени суток,
подскажите как к примеру посчитать кол-во "передач" для player_name 106.

```
    [list_match_timeline] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => передача
                    [1] => взятие_ворот
                    [2] => удаление_2_мин
                    [3] => командный_штраф
                    [4] => удаление_2_мин
                    [5] => взятие_ворот
                    [6] => удаление_2_мин
                    [7] => взятие_ворот
                    [8] => передача
                    [9] => взятие_ворот
                    [10] => конец_первого_периода
                    [11] => удаление_2_мин
                    [12] => взятие_ворот
                    [13] => передача
                    [14] => взятие_ворот
                    [15] => взятие_ворот
                    [16] => взятие_ворот
                    [17] => передача
                    [18] => взятие_ворот
                    [19] => передача
                    [20] => взятие_ворот
                    [21] => конец_второго_периода
                    [22] => удаление_2_мин
                    [23] => передача
                    [24] => взятие_ворот
                    [25] => передача
                    [26] => взятие_ворот
                    [27] => передача
                    [28] => взятие_ворот
                    [29] => передача
                    [30] => взятие_ворот
                    [31] => конец_третьего_периода
                )

            [player] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 106
                    [1] => 118
                    [2] => 171
                    [3] => 1
                    [4] => 169
                    [5] => 176
                    [6] => 122
                    [7] => 117
                    [8] => 106
                    [9] => 174
                    [10] => 1
                    [11] => 124
                    [12] => 118
                    [13] => 124
                    [14] => 122
                    [15] => 154
                    [16] => 118
                    [17] => 106
                    [18] => 122
                    [19] => 106
                    [20] => 122
                    [21] => 1
                    [22] => 124
                    [23] => 176
                    [24] => 174
                    [25] => 117
                    [26] => 118
                    [27] => 114
                    [28] => 115
                    [29] => 118
                    [30] => 114
                    [31] => 1
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в stdClass объекте есть 2 массивы.

Как я понял из их структуры например индексы player_name например 106 соответствуют индексам передач.

Для подсчета количества передач для 106 номера могу предложить следующий алгоритм:

```
$types = list_match_timeline->type; //first array
$players = list_match_timeline->player //second array

$allTypesForOnePlayer = [];
$countallTypesForOnePlayer = 0;

foreach ($players as $key => $player) {
  if ($value == 106) {
    $allTypesForOnePlayer[] = $types[$key];
    $countallTypesForOnePlayer++;
  }
}

var_dump($allTypesForOnePlayer); //список всех передач для пользователя 106
echo $countallTypesForOnePlayer; // ко-во передач для 106
```

Comment: Код не совсем верно считает. Он счетает все совпадения с 106, а не только "передачи"

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу по другому. Собрал новый массив из двух и пересчитал нужные значения.

```
$match_timeline_types   = $stats->list_match_timeline->type;
$match_timeline_players = $stats->list_match_timeline->player;

//Собираем массив
$timeline_key = 0;
// Match timeline
$stats->match_timelines = array();
foreach ($match_timeline_types as $key => $match_timeline_type) {

    // Timelines
    $stats->match_timelines[$timeline_key] = array(
        'type'      => $match_timeline_types[$key],
        'player'    => $match_timeline_players[$key],
        );

$timeline_key ++;

$pass =0;
foreach($stats->match_timelines as $timeline){
        if($timeline['player'] == $this->item->spsoccer_player_id && $timeline['type'] == 'передача'){
            $pass++;
   }
}
```

Спасибо.