# Сопоставить и пересчитать значения в обьектах и массивах

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Доброго времени суток,
есть объект

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [pids] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [spsoccer_player_id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [spsoccer_player_id] => 2
                    )
... и т.д.

     [matchs] => Array
            (
               [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [spsoccer_match_id] => 32
                        [teamone] => 13
                        [teamtwo] => 12
                        [list_teamone_score] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [player_name] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 54
                                        [1] => 55
                                        [2] => 36
                                        [3] => 54
                                    )

                                [player_goal] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 1
                                        [1] => 1
                                        [2] => 1
                                        [3] => 1
                                    )

                                [player_assist] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 
                                        [1] => 
                                        [2] => 
                                        [3] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [list_teamtwo_score] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [player_name] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 23
                                        [1] => 14
                                    )

                                [player_goal] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 1
                                        [1] => 1
                                    )

                                [player_assist] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 
                                        [1] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [list_match_timeline] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [min] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 01:45
                                        [1] => 01:45
                                        [2] => 03:12
                                        [3] => 03:12
                                        [4] => 15:02
                                        [5] => 15:02
                                        [6] => 20:00
                                        [7] => 27:17
                                        [8] => 27:17
                                        [9] => 30:34
                                        [10] => 32:50
                                        [11] => 37:52
                                        [12] => 37:52
                                        [13] => 40:00
                                        [14] => 53:52
                                        [15] => 53:52
                                        [16] => 57:30
                                        [17] => 60:00
                                    )

                                [type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => передача
                                        [1] => взятие_ворот
                                        [2] => передача
                                        [3] => взятие_ворот
                                        [4] => передача
                                        [5] => взятие_ворот
                                        [6] => конец_первого_периода
                                        [7] => передача
                                        [8] => взятие_ворот
                                        [9] => удаление_2_мин
                                        [10] => удаление_2_мин
                                        [11] => передача
                                        [12] => взятие_ворот
                                        [13] => конец_второго_периода
                                        [14] => передача
                                        [15] => взятие_ворот
                                        [16] => удаление_2_мин
                                        [17] => конец_третьего_периода
                                    )

                                [team] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => team_two
                                        [1] => team_two
                                        [2] => team_one
                                        [3] => team_one
                                        [4] => team_two
                                        [5] => team_two
                                        [6] => team_two
                                        [7] => team_one
                                        [8] => team_one
                                        [9] => team_two
                                        [10] => team_one
                                        [11] => team_one
                                        [12] => team_one
                                        [13] => team_one
                                        [14] => team_one
                                        [15] => team_one
                                        [16] => team_one
                                        [17] => team_two
                                    )

                                [player] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 14
                                        [1] => 23
                                        [2] => 31
                                        [3] => 54
                                        [4] => 1
                                        [5] => 14
                                        [6] => 16
                                        [7] => 50
                                        [8] => 55
                                        [9] => 18
                                        [10] => 52
                                        [11] => 48
                                        [12] => 36
                                        [13] => 2
                                        [14] => 50
                                        [15] => 54
                                        [16] => 52
                                        [17] => 7
                                    )

                            )

                        [teamone_players] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 28
                                [1] => 29
                                [2] => 30
                                [3] => 31
                                [4] => 32
                                [5] => 33
                                [6] => 34
                                [7] => 35
                                [8] => 36
                                [9] => 37
                                [10] => 38
                                [11] => 39
                                [12] => 40
                                [13] => 41
                                [14] => 42
                                [15] => 43
                                [16] => 44
                                [17] => 45
                                [18] => 46
                                [19] => 47
                                [20] => 48
                                [21] => 49
                                [22] => 50
                                [23] => 51
                                [24] => 52
                                [25] => 53
                                [26] => 54
                                [27] => 55
                                [28] => 56
                            )

                        [teamtwo_players] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 4
                                [2] => 5
                                [3] => 7
                                [4] => 10
                                [5] => 12
                                [6] => 13
                                [7] => 14
                                [8] => 15
                                [9] => 16
                                [10] => 17
                                [11] => 18
                                [12] => 19
                                [13] => 20
                                [14] => 23
                                [15] => 24
                                [16] => 26
                                [17] => 244
                            )

                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
    и т.д. ...
```

Подскажите как сопоставить и посчитать сколько раз [spsoccer_player_id] из первого объекта [pids] встречается во втором объекте [matchs] во всем массиве в объекте list_teamone_score -> player_name и так для каждого [spsoccer_player_id].

П.С. Надеюсь хоть что-то понятно из того что я написал ...

Comment: цикл `foreach` в помощь.

Comment: Мои попытки его использовать не привели к успеху, по этому тут и пишу

Comment: За вас никто не будет этого делать, показывайте примеры кодов, которые вы уже делали, делайте внятное описание и нормальный объект, а не дамп.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сопоставить и пересчитать значения массивов PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813468/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-php)